# Sorting Table is wrong when the sort button be pressed more than once?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have a problem here. I create program to add data to the table and sort it when i press the button. when i press the sort button once, it isn't wrong. but when i press again it is wrong. so why? please help me.
this is the code.

Nama Class

```
public class Nama  {
    private String nama;
    private int index;

    public Nama(String n,int i){
        nama=n;index=i;
    }
    void setData(String n,int i){
        nama=n;index=i;
    }
    String nama(){
        return nama;
    }
    int ind(){
        return index;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return(String.format("%s %d", nama,index));
    }


}
```

MergeSort Class

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class MergeSortS{


        public void merge_sort(int low,int high,Nama [] a){
            int mid;
            if(low<high) {
                   mid=(low+high)/2;
                   merge_sort(low,mid,a);
                   merge_sort(mid+1,high, a);
                   merge(low,mid,high,a);
            }
        }
        public void merge(int low,int mid,int high,Nama [] a){
            int h,i,j,k;
            Nama b[]=new Nama[50];
            h=low;
            i=low;
            j=mid+1;

            while((h<=mid)&&(j<=high)){
                if(a[h].nama().compareToIgnoreCase(a[j].nama())<0){
                    b[i]=a[h];
                    h++;
                }

                else{
                    b[i]=a[j];
                    j++;
                }

                i++;
            }
            if(h>mid){
                for(k=j;k<=high;k++){
                    b[i]=a[k];
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else{
                for(k=h;k<=mid;k++){
                    b[i]=a[k];
                    i++;
                }
            }
            for(k=low;k<=high;k++) a[k]=b[k];
        }
        public MergeSortS() {
        }

    }
```

Panel Class

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Kareem
 */
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JTable table;
    JTextField tf1,tf2,tf3,tf4;
    JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7;
    Vector rows,columns,temp;
    DefaultTableModel tabModel;
    String[]data = new String[3];
    String [] column = {"Nama", "Nim", "IP"};
    Nama[] n,nim,ip;
    MergeSortS mS;
    int c=0,index=0;

    public Panel(){
        this.setBounds(0,0,1280, 800);
        this.setLayout(null);
        inaTf();
        inaTab();
        inaBut();

        n= new Nama[50];
        nim= new Nama[50];
        ip= new Nama[50];
        mS=  new MergeSortS();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void inaTab(){
                        rows=new Vector();
                columns= new Vector();
                temp= new Vector();


                addColumns(column);

            tabModel=new DefaultTableModel();
            tabModel.setDataVector(rows,columns);

            table = new JTable(tabModel);
            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new 
               Dimension(500, 70));
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            table.setBounds(100,100,200,200);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
            scroll.setBounds(50,50,400,400);
            add(scroll);

    }
    public void inaBut(){
        b1=new JButton("add Row");
        b1.setBounds(50,600,90,25);
        add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        b2=new JButton("Delete Row");
        b2.setBounds(170,600,90,25);
        add(b2);
        b2.addActionListener(this);

        b3=new JButton("SortName");
        b3.setBounds(290,600,120,25);
        add(b3);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b5=new JButton("SortNim");
        b5.setBounds(290,650,120,25);
        add(b5);
        b5.addActionListener(this);
        b6=new JButton("SortIP");
        b6.setBounds(290,700,120,25);
        add(b6);
        b6.addActionListener(this);

        b4=new JButton("RESET");
        b4.setBounds(170,650,90,25);
        add(b4);
        b4.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void inaTf(){
        tf1=new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(640,50,90,25);
        add(tf1);

        JLabel l1= new JLabel("Nama \t: ");
        l1.setBounds(530,50,90,25);
        add(l1);

        tf2=new JTextField();
        tf2.setBounds(640,80,90,25);
        add(tf2);

        JLabel l2= new JLabel("Nim     : ");
        l2.setBounds(530,80,90,25);
        add(l2);

        tf3=new JTextField();
        tf3.setBounds(640,110,90,25);
        add(tf3);

        JLabel l3= new JLabel("IPK      : ");
        l3.setBounds(530,110,90,25);
        add(l3);

        tf4=new JTextField();
        tf4.setBounds(640,140,90,25);
        add(tf4);

        JLabel l4= new JLabel("Hapus Baris ke ");
        l4.setBounds(530,140,120,25);
        add(l4);
    }

        public void addRow() 
        {
                Vector r;
                r = createBlankElement();
                rows.addElement(r);

                table.addNotify();
        }
        public void addRow(String [] data) 
        {       
                Vector r=new Vector();
                r = isi(data);
                rows.addElement(r);

                table.addNotify();
        }

        public Vector createBlankElement() 
        {
                Vector t = new Vector();
                t.addElement((String) " ");
                t.addElement((String) " ");
                t.addElement((String) " ");

                return t;
        }
        public Vector isi(String[] data) {
                Vector t = new Vector();

                    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                        t.addElement((String) data[j]);
                    }


                return t;
        }
        public void addColumns(String[] colName) {
                for(int i=0;i<colName.length;i++)
                columns.addElement((String) colName[i]);
        }
        void deleteRow(int index) {
             if(index!=-1) { 
                rows.removeElementAt(index);
                table.addNotify();
               }


        }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{
        if(e.getSource()==b1){
            data[0]=tf1.getText()+" "+index;
            n[index]=new Nama(data[0],index);
            data[1]=tf2.getText();
            nim[index]=new Nama(data[1],index);
            data[2]=tf3.getText()+rows.size();
            ip[index]=new Nama (data[2],index);
            c=c+1;
            index=index+1;
            addRow(data);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==b2){
            int i;
            i=Integer.parseInt(tf4.getText());

            deleteRow(i);

//            for(;i<rows.size();i++){
//                n[i]=n[i+1];
//            }

        }
        if(e.getSource()==b3){

          mS.merge_sort(0, rows.size()-1, n);
          temp.setSize(rows.size());
          for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
                temp.set(i, rows.get(n[i].ind()));

           }
           for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
                rows.set(i, temp.get(i));
           }
        }

        if(e.getSource()==b4){
            rows.setSize(0);
            temp.setSize(0);
            for(int i=0;i<index;i++)n[i]=null;
            index=0;
        }
        if(e.getSource()==b5){
             mS.merge_sort(0, rows.size()-1, nim);
             temp.setSize(rows.size());
           for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++){
                temp.set(i, rows.get(nim[i].ind()));

           }

           for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++){
                rows.set(i, temp.get(i));
           }
        }
        if(e.getSource()==b6){
             mS.merge_sort(0, rows.size()-1, ip);
             temp.setSize(rows.size());
           for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++){
                temp.add(i, rows.get(ip[i].ind()));

           }

           for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++){
                rows.set(i, temp.get(i));
           }
        }
           repaint();


        }
        catch (Throwable t){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "AAAAAA");   
        }

    }

}
```

Frame Class

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Kareem
 */
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame(){
        super("Penghitung Gaji");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(1280, 800);
        this.getContentPane().add(new Panel());
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
    }
}
```

Thanks. And Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you please provide an example input, (first) correct output, and (second) wrong output?

Comment: input :
["aa","sss","ff"]
["vv","dd","ff"]
["ba","sss","ff"]
["za","sss","ff"]

when i pressed sortName it must be like this:
["aa","sss","ff"]
["ba","sss","ff"]
["vv","dd","ff"]
["za","sss","ff"]

Comment: You know tables have inbuilt support for sorting and filter...right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Dashing through the snow
> In a one-horse open sleigh
> O'er the fields we go
> Laughing all the way
>
> Bells on bobtail ring'
> Making spirits bright
> What fun it is to ride and sing
> A sleighing song tonight!
>
>     Jingle bells, jingle bells,
>     Jingle all the way.
>     Oh! what fun it is to ride
>     In a one-horse open sleigh.
>
>     Jingle bells, jingle bells, ....
> ```

- [song singing from code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingle_Bells), please to apologize me if isn't this one your favorite song
- can't comment or suggesting, excluding used LayoutManager in my code, I walked the path of least resistance, my endless lazyness

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

.
.
.

from code

.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class MyFrame {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JTable table;
    private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel buttonPanelSouth = new JPanel();
    private JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4;
    private JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4;
    private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7;
    private String[] columnNames = {"Nama", "Nim", "IP", "Hapus Baris ke"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"igor", "B01_125-358", "1.124.01.125", true},
        {"lenka", "B21_002-242", "21.124.01.002", true},
        {"peter", "B99_001-358", "99.124.01.001", false},
        {"zuza", "B12_100-242", "12.124.01.100", true},
        {"jozo", "BUS_011-358", "99.124.01.011", false},
        {"nora", "B09_154-358", "9.124.01.154", false},
        {"xantipa", "B01_001-358", "1.124.01.001", false},};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 3:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };

    public MyFrame() {
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        DefaultTableCellRenderer stringRenderer =
                (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getDefaultRenderer(String.class);
        stringRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table,
                ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        centerPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        centerPanel.add(pane);
        centerPanel.add(pane);
//        
        b1 = new JButton("add Row");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.addRow(new Object[]{(tf1.getText()).trim(),
                            (tf2.getText()).trim(), (tf3.getText()).trim(), true});
            }
        });
        b2 = new JButton("Delete Row");
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int rowToDelete = 0;
                int rowToModel = 0;
                if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
                    rowToDelete = table.getSelectedRow();
                    rowToModel = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowToDelete);
                    model.removeRow(rowToModel);
                }
            }
        });
        b3 = new JButton("RESET");
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                table.getRowSorter().setSortKeys(null);
            }
        });
        b4 = new JButton("SortName");
        b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(0);
            }
        });
        b5 = new JButton("SortNim");
        b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TableRowSorter rowSorter = (TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter();
                List<SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();
                SortKey sortKey = new SortKey(1, SortOrder.ASCENDING);
                sortKeys.add(sortKey);
                rowSorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
                rowSorter.sort();
            }
        });
        b6 = new JButton("SortIP");
        b6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TableRowSorter rowSorter = (TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter();
                List<SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();
                SortKey sortKey = new SortKey(2, SortOrder.DESCENDING);
                sortKeys.add(sortKey);
                SortKey sortKey1 = new SortKey(1, SortOrder.ASCENDING);
                sortKeys.add(sortKey1);
                SortKey sortKey2 = new SortKey(0, SortOrder.UNSORTED);
                sortKeys.add(sortKey2);
                rowSorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
                rowSorter.sort();
            }
        });
        b7 = new JButton("SortIP");
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 50, 0));
        buttonPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 10, 2, 10));
        buttonPanel.add(b1);
        buttonPanel.add(b2);
//
        buttonPanelSouth.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4, 5, 5));
        buttonPanelSouth.add(b3);
        buttonPanelSouth.add(b7);
        b7.setVisible(false);
        buttonPanelSouth.add(b4);
        buttonPanelSouth.add(b5);
        buttonPanelSouth.add(b6);
        centerPanel.add(buttonPanelSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//
        l1 = new JLabel("Nama : ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        l2 = new JLabel("Nim  : ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        tf2 = new JTextField();
        l3 = new JLabel("IPK : ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        tf3 = new JTextField();
        l4 = new JLabel("Hapus Baris ke :", JLabel.RIGHT);
        tf4 = new JTextField();
        textFieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 10, 10));
        textFieldPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        textFieldPanel.add(l1);
        textFieldPanel.add(tf1);
        textFieldPanel.add(l2);
        textFieldPanel.add(tf2);
        textFieldPanel.add(l3);
        textFieldPanel.add(tf3);
        textFieldPanel.add(l4);
        textFieldPanel.add(tf4);
//
        northPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        northPanel.add(textFieldPanel);
        northPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//
        frame.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(centerPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No where do you actually tell the `TableModel` that it's contents have changed...

Now, the thing that weirds me out, is you are keeping a `Vector` of the rows outside of the model...

```
mS.merge_sort(0, rows.size()-1, n);
temp.setSize(rows.size());
for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
    temp.set(i, rows.get(n[i].ind()));
}
for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
    rows.set(i, temp.get(i)); // This is doing nothing...
}
```

Once the data has been handed to the table model, you should not be interacting with it, unless you are willing to notify the table model of the changes.

Personally, I would simply use the [inbuilt sorting capabilities of the `JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

ps- I would also, strongly, encourage you to learn how to use layout managers, they will save your sanity in the long run