# JTable row sorter - IllegalArgumentException: Invalid SortKey

Tags: java, swing, jtable, illegalargumentexception, tablerowsorter

Can someone help me with this? 
It was working until I changed something trying to optimaze it... damn!

This is my table model:

```
class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        private String[] columnNames = {"Last Name","First Name","Next Visit"};     //column header labels
        Object[][] data = new Object[100][3];

        public void reloadJTable(List<Customer> list) {
            for(int i=0; i< list.size(); i++){
                data[i][0] = list.get(i).getLastName();
                data[i][1] = list.get(i).getFirstName();
                if (list.get(i).getNextVisit()==null) {
                    data[i][2] = "NOT SET";
                } else {
                    String date = displayDateFormat.format(list.get(i).getNextVisit().getTime());
                    data[i][2] = date;
                }
                model.addRow(data);
            }
        }

        public void clearJTable() {
            model.setRowCount(0);
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * editable.
        */ 
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is how I implement the JTable:

```
// these declarations are all private shared across the model
JTable customerTbl;
MyTableModel model;
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>(); 
SimpleDateFormat displayDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("EEE dd-MM-yyyy 'at' hh:mm");

//JTable configuration
model = new MyTableModel();
customerTbl = new JTable(model);
model.reloadJTable(customers);
customerTbl.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);  //enable row sorters                     

DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter)customerTbl.getRowSorter());  //default sort by Last Name
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add( new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
sorter.setSortKeys(list);  //EXCEPTION HERE
sorter.sort();

customerTbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);   //set Last Name column preferred width
customerTbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(80);    //set First Name column preferred width
customerTbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);   //set Last Visit column preferred width
```

I'm getting the following exception triggered on:

sorter.setSortKeys(list);

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid SortKey
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.setSortKeys(Unknown Source)
    at com.vetapp.customer.CustomersGUI.<init>(CustomersGUI.java:128)
    at com.vetapp.main.VetApp.main(VetApp.java:31)
```

I believe it has to do with the TableColumnModel which is not created correctly...

Comment: My guess is the table thinks it has no columns in it. what does customerTbl.getColumnCount() return?

Comment: That was right! It was returning 0..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that the column count is returning `0` from the `TableModel's` super class `DefaultTableModel`. You need to override this method

```
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
   return columnNames.length;
}
```

---

Another side but potentially fatal issue is the fact that `getColumnClass` is returning the class of elements within the `TableModel`. This will throw a `NullPointerException` if the table is empty. Use a class literal instead such as `String.class`.

Maintaining a separate backing data array is unnecessary for `DefaultTableModel`. It has already has its own data vector. This approach is used when extending `AbstractTableModel`.

Comment: It would probably be better to extend AbstractTableModel instead. Or at the very least, use the DefaultTableModel's underlying data vector instead of maintaining a separate array.

Comment: @damo please [see how RowSorter a SortKey(s) works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661998/sorting-table-is-wrong-when-the-sort-button-be-pressed-more-than-once/16664124#16664124)

Comment: @mKorbel I understand how RowSorter works, I was just commenting on the fact that extending DefaultTableModel without using its backing data vectors is a bad idea. What's the point of extending it if you're just going to override all of its functionality? Rather than overriding DefaultTableModel's getColumnCount(), call its setColumnIdentifiers(Object[] newIdentifiers) method instead. OR if the OP has some compelling reason to maintain his own data, he should use AbstractTableModel instead.