# "Super" and "this" on DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

My class extended from DefaultTableModel

I try:

```
super.removeRow(...);
```

And

```
this.removeRow(...);
```

Why do they both work?

Comment: @APoliteBoy cause `Your class` is a `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: @A Polite Boy please whats what

Comment: that's the way objects works, has nothing to do with `defaulttablemodel` or `swing` is `oop`

Comment: @mKorbel What `why.........` ?

Comment: search here for AbstractTableModel, here are a few most complex code examples, the same methods you can to override in DeafultTableModel, but then I'm miss any reason to override that because this method is accesible in whole JVM instance, and advantage of DeafultTableModel is call whatever from any corners of current JVM, then this or super inside class extends DefaultTableModel are useless chars, removeRow will be execured without this or..., the same as from JButtons Action, etc

Comment: @A Polite Boy here is  [quite refference code for DefaultTableMode (please ignore my ego) why was there my why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16664124/714968)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not an answer, but `this.whatever` can be pretty misspeled in most complex Swing GUI

```
super.removeRow(...);
```

And

```
this.removeRow(...);
```

---

should be (my view to avoid ....)

`myTableModel.removeRow()` - e.g. `((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(row);`

or you override in XxxTableModel

`public void removeRowAt(int row) {`

Answer (score 5):

`super` refers to the super (parent) type's implementation.

`this` refers the the current type's implementation, if one exists, otherwise looks up the inheritance tree, ie. does the same as `super`.

Depending on how your class extends `DefaultTableModel`, they might be calling the same method.

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer.. has nothing to do about swing is about oop.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they are calling same method i.e. `removeRow` in parent class for your case.

Only for the case when you decide to override `removeRow` in your child class then you can make a call to `super.removeRow()` like this:

```
@Override
void removeRow() {
   // call parent class's removeRow
   super.removeRow()
   // rest of implementation
}
```